# How to compare a String from Intent.getStringExtra()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Can I compare the data from `getStringExtra()` with a string?
Sample code:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String path = intent.getStringExtra("category");

  if(path == "car"){
       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.subcategory, car));
  } else {
       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.subcategory, bike));
  }
```

Why is the script is not running?

Comment: try: `path == "car"` change to `path.equals("car")`

Comment: Use `if ("car".equals(path))`, this will handle the case that path is null.

Comment: wow, great.. i use this code if ("car".equals(path)) and the script running,, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing two strings to check if they are equal in java you should use equals().

In your case you should change your comparison line to

```
 if(path.equals("car"))
```

In java the equals() compares the actual contents of your strings while == will only compare to see if the two references are equal

Answer (score 2):

use

```
path.equals("car") "or"
path.contains("car") "or"
path.equalsIgnoreCase("car") "or"
```

as this is more precise

Answer (score 0):

`==` the contrast is the memory address, equals contrast is the attribute value.

Comment: == the contrast is the memory address,equals contrast is the attribute value